# How Do I Let Google's Web Crawler Access a Bootstrap Theme?

Tags: reactjs, seo

I have a bootstrap CSS theme added to my React/Nextjs project, and google's web scraper cannot access it due to bootstrap/robots.txt getting in the way. This causes the web console to suggest that my page isn't mobile-friendly, since bootstrap won't load.
How do I allow Google to scrape that file?
Here is the bootstrap link in the head of my page:

And this is the error the google console is giving me:
https://i.stack.imgur.com/iKm5f.png

Answer (score 0):

Just edit the robots.txt file on your webserver.